# How to assign Php variable value to Javascript variable?

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to pass a PHP variable to Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766041/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-javascript)

I am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $ctnme = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$cnme = explode("/",$ctnme);
echo $cname = $cnme[1];
?>
var spge = <?php echo $cname; ?> ;
alert(spge);
</script>
```

The value doesn't alert. What is the mistake?

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/05/can-you-set-javascript-variable-value.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Essentially:

```
<?php
//somewhere set a value
$var = "a value";
?>

<script>
// then echo it into the js/html stream
// and assign to a js variable
spge = '<?php echo $var ;?>';

// then
alert(spge);

</script>
```

Comment: You could have problems if $var contains single quotes, carriage returns...

Comment: I agree, however the I get the impression the question seems to have changed substantially since I first replied making this reply look rather redundant now.  IIRC it was a question about the whole principle of how to pass a var, now its an array.

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/05/can-you-set-javascript-variable-value.html

Comment: when i alert it, it shows empty, can anyone help me find a solution, also i would like to know where should I type those script, as of now i have it at end of page

Answer (score 12):

The most secure way (in terms of special character and data type handling) is using [`json_encode()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
var spge = <?php echo json_encode($cname); ?>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **json_encode()** if possible (PHP 5.2+).

See this one (maybe duplicate?): [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Answer (score 3):

Put quotes around the `<?php echo $cname; ?>` to make sure Javascript accepts it as a string, also consider escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
**var spge = '';** 
alert(spge);
```