# How to assign a PHP variable to a JavaScript variable inside JavaScript code? The whole file is PHP though

Tags: javascript, php

-------------php code ends here-------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = <?php echo $tweetText; ?>; 
    var f = twemoji.parse(e);
    document.write(f);
</script>
```

-------------php code starts here-------------

If I put single quotes or double quotes before and after  then it matches any ' or " inside the tweetText and doesn't let the string print to screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign Php variable value to Javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895842/how-to-assign-php-variable-value-to-javascript-variable)

Comment: Well you have to quote that string, but I can assure that you will need to more than just echo out the tweet. There will be quotes and junk in there that will cause JavaScript errors.

Comment: you should use `json_encode` php function. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works fine, just add ,,addslashes" to escape quotes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = '<?php echo addslashes($tweetText); ?>'; 
    var f = twemoji.parse(e);
    document.write(f);
</script>
```

Comment: And what if the string has a double-quote in it? It would come out as var e = 'He said, \"Yes, that\'s it.\"';

Comment: Have fun removing slashes in your code. This is not the correct solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = '<?php echo $tweetText; ?>'; 
    var f = twemoji.parse(e);
    document.write(f);
</script>
```

That's it

Comment: And if the Tweet looks like this:

I love that you're a Leo.

Comment: can you explain your comment please @Halfstop?

Comment: I tried and this works fine, I don't understend what is the problem and why I get minus?

Comment: Does this look like valid JS? var e = 'I love that you're a Lew.';

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be with json_encode as @vivek said in a comment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var e = <?php echo json_encode($tweetText); ?>;
var f = twemoji.parse(e);
document.write(f);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the whole string inside doublequotes, then escape the same - double quotes - inside the javascript string, with a simple str function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var e = "<?php echo str_replace('"','\"',$tweetText); ?>"; 
var f = twemoji.parse(e);
document.write(f);
</script>
```