# How to set PHP tag $value into a Javascript parameter?

Tags: javascript, php

Script I'm using:

```
if(isset($_GET['cap']) && isset($captions[$_GET['cap']])){
    $cap = $captions[$_GET['cap']];
}

if(isset($cap)){

}
```

How can I insert the `$cap` inside a JavaScript parameter?

Example:

```
tracks: [{
    file: 'http://mylink.com/caption.srt',
    label: 'English',
    kind: 'captions',
    'default': true
}],
```

Comment: Like this - `cap: '<?php echo $cap;?>'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign Php variable value to Javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895842/how-to-assign-php-variable-value-to-javascript-variable)

Comment: So, Can I simply insert this instead of link in "file:"?

Comment: Is your JavaScript inside the php file or whether they are separate?

Comment: @Rohith Inside!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['cap']) && isset($captions[$_GET['cap']])){
    $cap = $captions[$_GET['cap']];
?>
<script>
   tracks: [{
      file:<?php echo $cap; ?>,
      label: 'English',
      kind: 'captions',
     'default': true
}],

 </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

You can combine JS and PHP, by keeping JS inside a PHP `if` statement, it shall work as you expect

OR

You may try this:

```
 <?php

if(isset($_GET['cap']) && isset($captions[$_GET['cap']])){
    $cap = $captions[$_GET['cap']];

 echo"<script>tracks:file:".$cap.",label: 'English',kind: 'captions','default':true}],</script>"


}
?>
```

Comment: Value "tracks" is inside an echo, I think will not work.

Comment: It's working! I did some changes in your script and it's perfect right now, thanks! It wasn't working because I forgot the ".$cap." syntax to call the php function.

Answer (score 0):

In your script

```
 <script>

   var cap = '<?php echo $cap; ?>'
   tracks: [{
      file:cap,
      label: 'English',
      kind: 'captions',
     'default': true
}],

 </script>
```

Now cap is can be use   in your scripts.

Comment: How can I insert the $cap onto "file:" instead of link?

Comment: Once you share the `cap` variable in your file  `cap` has value of `$cap` .You can use it your script!

Comment: make sure the js and php scipts are loaded in the same file!

Answer (score 0):

This would assign the value into **file**

```
tracks: [{
    file: '<b><?= $cap ?></b>',
    label: 'English',
    kind: 'captions',
    'default': true
}],
```