# String from PHP doesn't work in JS

Tags: javascript, php, string

I'm getting the string from controller:

```
var x = '<?php echo addcslashes($this->x, "'") ?>';
```

The parsed result is:

```
var x = '<script>alert(\'x\')</script>';
```

Error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

I tried to assign the string directly from JS and it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5895936/5541139

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/4511459

Comment: Do you want your x variable to actually contain the _text_ `<script>…`, or what? What exactly would be the purpose of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign Php variable value to Javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895842/how-to-assign-php-variable-value-to-javascript-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The alert is coming up because the first character in the alert is a slash (the unexpected token) the second slash escapes the ' so the alert never closes either.

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve honestly with the script tags etc seems as you're already inside a script when it gets called (unless you're printing it to a page, in which case you're better off adding it to an event handler or something.)