# How to use PHP variable in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I know you can't directly use PHP variables inside javascript code, but is there a way around it? I need to use these parameter's in javascript:

```
username: '<?php echo $user_id;?>.example.co.uk',
password: 'example',
```

Instead of showing the $user_id variable, it outputs: `"Resource id #4.example.co.uk"`

I'm quite new to javascript so I'm finding it pretty tricky.

Thanks for any help

Edit: I am taking the $user_id variable from the URL like so:

```
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["user_id"]);
```

so shouldn't it just have the set value from the URL?

Comment: Where `$user_id;` comes from? looks like result resource

Comment: What you have looks okay - from the JS end. From the PHP end, you're trying to echo *something*; you need to be echoing a string (else you'll get this).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to pass a PHP variable to Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766041/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-javascript)

Comment: You can use PHP variables "inside" Javascript just fine, when your Javascript is generated by PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Resource id #4* means u have just not complete the mysql query

**mysql_query** returns Resource id

u have to fetch the data using `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array())` and then use

[written here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN
>   and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a
>   resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements,
>   INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success
>   or FALSE on error.

### UPDATE

don't use `mysql_real_escape string` for GET data..instead use `(int)$_GET['id']`

[see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

> If no connection is found or
>   established, an E_WARNING level error
>   is generated

Comment: Hi diEcho, thanks for your reply. I am taking the $user_id variable like so: $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["user_id"]); so I'm not sure how I would use the while... code. Could you show me please? Thanks

Comment: `mysql_query returns Resource id #4`. `#4` is not true in all the cases

Comment: I have removed the real_escape part so now I have $user_id = $_GET["user_id"]; but I'm not sure what to put in the (int) section. After just removing the real_escape code the output is still the same

Comment: u are retrieving data from database using that user_id...right?? so then u simple `mysql_query('your query');` and then fetch data using`mysql_fetch_array()` and then do whatever u want...debug one by one

Comment: I'm not using user_id to touch the database in any way, all I want it to do is display the username on the page so that people can access different URLs to use different usernames (internal thing)

Comment: I tried setting $user_id like this instead to see if it was the GET that was causing the problem: $user_id = "test"; but this still outputs the same resource error (but it echoes fine elsewhere on the page)

Comment: but where is that usename?? you r only sending user_id ( i think it's reference to database entry of that user)..or tell me where is the username?? is it also sent by GET ??

Comment: ok so your `user_id is `string` not an `integer`...if it is text then try with addslashes($_GET['user_id']`

Comment: Hi diEcho, I tried moving the $user_id variable into the javascript code as well instead of the <head> area and it now works, not sure why :S. So this is working: username: '<?php $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["user_id"]);; echo $user_id;?>.example.co.uk',  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little rusty on PHP, but this may work:

```
<? //start HTML/Javascript code... 
    echo'var variable = ' . $user_id . '.example.co.uk';
    //finish HTML/Javascript here..
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign that php value in any html object then you use the object value in js page

for example

**PHP**:

```
$phpvalue = $_GET["sid"];
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $phpvalue ;?>" id="txtsamp" />
```

**JS**:

```
var phpval = document.getElementById('txtsamp').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected only one column (and expect 1 row), you can use:

```
$user_id = mysql_result($user_id, 0);
```

which would fetch the 1st column of the 1st row of the result set `$user_id`.

But for clarity's sake you should rename the variable $user_id, because it's not an ID but a resource (so call it `$userQuery` or something =)).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `result` of a `mysql_query()` directly. Instead, you have to use `mysql_result()` or something similar (depending on your SQL query).